# Sci-fi movie with a a large machine or ship that was either processing or "eating" people

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

This one may be a challenge simply based on the limited details I have to give. I saw a couple of minutes worth of this movie when I was younger and was pretty freaked out by the bits that I caught.

- I would guess this movie was from the late 80's or 90's based on the quality but I could be off.  I was in the US watching cable I believe, could be from a different country.
- The scene I saw was a large machine or ship that was either processing or "eating" people [I don't know if they were dead or alive] perhaps for fuel.  They may have been pre-chopped up, but I can't remember.
- The machine/ship seemed to be in the middle of a barren red area - Perhaps Mars?
- There was quite a bit of gore in this scene - I don't remember seeing anyone living.

I have no other details to go off of and will consider deleting this post if it is a pointless hunt.  I will research any suggestions as soon as I can because I would love to find this movie and actually watch it.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

These bodies / body parts were on a conveyor belt being fed into the machine/ship type thing.

Comment: Sounds like "The Mangler" (1995) http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113762/

Comment: Hmmm from what I can see, I'm not sure its the one BUT I am headed home from work right now and will inspect further soon.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Could it be The Wall by Pink Floyd? This had people being fed into a giant grinder that was making hamburger.

Comment: Looks like someone else was looking for the same movie: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Lj2MCcajAVAJ:movies.stackexchange.com/questions/36429/scifi-movie-from-early-to-mid-90s-with-humans-on-a-conveyor-belt-being-killed+&cd=6&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: TV series _Lexx_? We've already had question(s) about it.

Comment: Chanandler Bong might be right. See the last minute of [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sZg43WxUs8).

Comment: @ChanandlerBong Yes Indeed!  That was the one!  Feel free to turn that into an answer and I'll accept asap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're after 1997-2002 TV series [Lexx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexx).

> Lexx is a science fiction television series that follows the
>   adventures of a group of mismatched individuals aboard the organic
>   space craft Lexx.
>
> The Lexx is a bio-engineered planet-destroying bioship in the shape of
>   a giant wingless dragonfly. **It was grown by ingesting organ
>   collections from the protein bank on the Cluster**, the seat of the
>   Divine Order, for use by His Divine Shadow.

The [feeding scene](https://youtu.be/7sZg43WxUs8?t=576), that matches your description can be seen in the first episode.

Comment: Thank you again @Chanandler Bong - I have literally been thinking about this show at least once a week for the past 10'ish years.  Now I need to find and watch the series.

Comment: It's on Amazon Prime video. I've been watching it. Corny but good.

Answer (score 2):

War of the Worlds (2005), the one with Tom Cruise, contains a scene where a Martian tripod is harvesting people and processing them.  This seems part of the Martians plan to terraform (so to speak) the Earth to Martian standards.  This may explain why the background you recall was red (Red Weed in the book).

Processed human gore was sprayed to fertilize the martianized landscape.

This older answer discusses what the tripods were doing spraying

[What were the tripods spraying and what does it have to do with the red weed in War of the Worlds?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/26533/what-were-the-tripods-spraying-and-what-does-it-have-to-do-with-the-red-weed-in/26536#26536)

Comment: "War of the Worlds (2005), the one with Tom Cruise, contains a scene where a Martian tripod is harvesting people and processing them." - it does?  What the hell was I watching?  This wasn't just the Director's Cut DVD version?

Comment: @AndrewMattson, google up the "Not my blood" scene where Tom and a girl, and a guy going loony were holed up in a basement.  Outside the tripods are picking up bodies, and then spraying out gore.  They are watching through a basement window.  The loony starts going berserk, crying "Not MY blood" and Tom has to shut him down.  There's also a another scene inside a tripod where living captives are being pulled one at a time from a cage.  I don't recall if you see the gore in that one

Comment: Though I have to admit the conveyors in War Of the Worlds were more tentacle like than belt like.  Lexx had a conveyor belt, but I don't recall blood.

Comment: The "loony" was played by Tim Robbins.

Comment: @infixed - I remember him flipping out, I just wasn't paying attention to it beyond them grabbing people.  Wow. Gotta watch it again, now.